# How can i use “App card” without live website?

Tags: android, twitter, android-twitter, twitter-fabric

I am an android developer.
I am using [Twitter Kit](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/overview) for composing tweets from my android application. 
I want to drive my application installations by using "App Card" as described in the documentation here [App Card](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/app).
As per my understanding i need a live website to add meta tags which contains my app details. 
But i don't have live website( or hosted link) to add meta tags. 
Is there any possible way to use "App Card" for android without website link.

My idea to use App Card for launching application if it is installed or launching the store application with my application install option.

Please suggest me if there is any possibility to achieve the feature by using Twitter Kit or any alternative ways.

Added twitter developer forum thread for reference https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-can-i-use-app-card-without-live-website/34539